# Enter safe mode on Windows 11 during PC boot, without restarting from booted Windows

Tags: windows

So I was trying to find out how to do it.

But all answers are talking about restarting and pressing shift. Is this a joke? What if I can't even see Windows screen after bios boot? I need to access safe mode during PC boot.
I have black screen when I using built-in video card instead of external one.
F8 opens boot menu for me, so I can't use it.
What other choices?

Comment: No other choices.

Comment: You have tried the restart options.   Can you shut down and start up?  If so try F1 (or for your machine) repeatedly on the power button.

Comment: I'm not sure where the confusion lies, so I recommend you rephrase your question assuming that we don't understand what problem you are having. part of it may be terminology. you "boot into safemode" so you are not in "safemode" until you have completed booting, Safemode just disables non-essential services and drivers, so you can at least get a shell in order to fix whatever is wrong. are you trying to get the boot time video display issue fixed? that is likely in your firmware setup. or are you just trying to boot into safemode to fix a problem with your windows install?

Comment: @FrankThomas Nvidia driver causes black screen after Windows finishes booting when monitor is connected to a built-in video card (Intel) instead of Nvidia gpu. That's why I need safe mode to start Windows without this driver

Comment: does "black screen" mean that you don't see any output, but that the system remains booted, or are you refering to a "black screen reboot" where one second the system is running and the next second it powercycles and reboots/shutsdown? also can you comment on the existing answer providing info on how its non-responsive to your needs?

Answer (score 2):

There is no one-click way to get into Safe Mode from while booting in newer Windows systems, but you can still get the PC to boot in safe made through the Recovery Environment menu.

### Get into the Windows Recovery Environment (RE)

Windows 11 and Windows 10 automatically boot into the Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) if Windows fails to start three times in a row. Three consecutive failed attempts trigger this action. Booting to Safe Mode outside of Windows is achieved in the Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE)

1. Hold down the **power button** for **10 seconds** to turn off your device
2. Press the **power button** again to **turn on** your device
3. On the first sign that Windows has started (for example, some devices show the manufacturer’s logo when restarting) **hold down the power button** for **10 seconds** to turn off your device
4. Press the **power button** again **to turn** on your device.
5. When Windows restarts, **hold down the power button** for **10 seconds** to turn off your device
6. Press the **power button** again to **turn on** your device.
7. Allow your device to restart into ***Automatic Repair***, and select **Advanced options** to enter winRE

### Go to Safe Mode

Now that you are in winRE, you will follow these steps to take you to safe mode:

1. On the ***Choose an option*** screen, select **Troubleshoot** > **Advanced options** > **Startup Settings** > **Restart**
   [image]
2. After your device restarts, you'll see a list of options. **Select option 5** from the list, or press <kbd>F5</kbd> for ***Safe Mode with Networking*** (or the other corresponding numbers for the other Safe Modes):
   [image]